# Can a company lend an individual money "by way of business" if secured on a commercial property in the UK with any regulation?

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection, banking, loan

I am curious to know if a company can lend an individual money at a high interest rate for many years without a licence or following any guidelines in the UK
The loan was secured on a commercial property with a mortgage (first charge)
I believe under the FCA regulations it would not be a regulated activity but are there any other guidelines the lender would have to adhere to if making substantial amounts of money on the loan (rates way above the open market rate)

Comment: This question contains no periods, making it very difficult to read.  Editing by the OP is highly recommended.

Comment: 8 years, taken out in 2015